# Connecting to server with remotely generated SSH key

Tags: linux, debian, shell

I run a process on my server where I generate a public and private key. The public key I use for github. I was wondering, if I do a readout of the private key of the remote system, can I then save that value on my local system, and use that key to connect to the server?

All of the tutorials I have read are always talking about generating a key on the local system and copying it to the remove system but I was just wondering if it would work the other way around and if it is seen a secure.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you generating your key pair on your server? The private key should be generated on your workstation and should never leave there.

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys. I am generating it on the server because I want to clone my repo there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do from the server is to clone the repo, you should be using a [deploy key](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys). This is separate from the general-use key you use from your workstation, and it grants read access to a specific repository.

Your general-use key should be generated on your workstation and should never be transferred elsewhere. The public key from this keypair can be used *both* for accessing github as well as authenticating to your server.

Comment: Hi. Basically I do currently follow this procedure on my server as you said: https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys. But then, you are saying should generate another key on my workstation and copy the public bit into the server, and the private bit lives only on my workstation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Just ensure that the server's public is set as a **deploy key** in Github, not a "normal" key.